# Select latest updated categories based on their items

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database and there's a `categories` table like this:

```
id  name            parent
--------------------------
1   News            0
2   Analysis        0
3   Europe          1
4   Middle East     1
5   Asia            1
6   Americas        1
7   Commentaries    2
8   Interviews      2
9   Articles        2
10  Reports         2
```

And an `items` table like this:

```
id  created                 catid   title
---------------------------------------------
1   2013-08-12 20:15:00     3       Foo
2   2013-08-12 19:15:00     3       Bar
3   2013-08-12 18:15:00     4       Foobar
4   2013-08-12 17:15:00     4       Barfoor
5   2013-08-12 16:15:00     8       Boofar
6   2013-08-12 15:15:00     9       Farfar
7   2013-08-11 16:45:00     10      Farfarbar
8   2013-08-11 16:15:00     5       Foofoobar
10  2013-08-10 16:15:00     7       Foobarbar
```

What I want is to list to categories which are children of a specified parent and have latest items in them. For example if I want latest updated categories of **News** (catid=1) section, the result would be:

```
3   Europe
4   Middle East
5   Asia
```

Note that the results are ordered by their last update time.

Please consider that due to large amount of records, performance of the query is so important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join works pretty fast. Then use a group by to enable the aggregate `MAX()`-function to sort the output.

In the `WHERE`-clause you can choose the parent-id that you want to search for.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN items i
ON c.id = i.catid
WHERE c.parent = 1
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY MAX(i.created) DESC
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7e19/4/0)

**EDIT**

In the event of only single nestings, you can change the query as follows:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN items i
ON c.id = i.catid
WHERE c.parent = 1
OR c.parent IN (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE c.parent = 1)
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY MAX(i.created) DESC
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7e19/6/0)

If you need more nestings, you'd need to create stored procedures.
More information about this can be found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes).

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working, but if the categories become one or more level deeper? Is that possible to do that? (I know I haven't mentioned it in my question!)

Comment: @faridv what is the difference between my query with this one?

Comment: @MartyMcVry he does't wants time or any unique id's of rows, he wants only id and city name

Comment: From OP: "Note that the results are ordered by their last update time."

Comment: @NaveenKumar category id's are not important but the ordering of categories base on their items creation date is important.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to only want the children of a particular category.  It seems that you are asking which rows in categories have a parent of `1` and have rows in the `items` table:

```
select c.id, c.name
from categories c
where c.parent = 1 and
      exists (select 1 from items i where i.catid = c.id);
```

EDIT:

I have no idea what you mean by "latest" items.  But you can check for the 10 most recent in the items table by doing:

```
select c.id, c.name
from categories c
where c.parent = 1 and
      exists (select 1
              from (select i.*
                    from items i
                    order by created desc
                    limit 10
                   ) i
              where i.catid = c.id)
             );
```

Or using a join:

```
select c.id, c.name
from categories c join
     (select i.*
      from items i
      order by created desc
      limit 10
     ) i10
     on i.catid = c.id
where c.parent = 1
group by c.id, c.name
order by max(created) desc;
```

Comment: Where are you mentioning the latest updated categories in your query?

Comment: latest means newer based on the created field.

Comment: @faridv . . . I didn't understand the question.  You wanted the results *sorted* by the created date.  I originally thought you were just filtering on the items table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7e19/7)

```
SELECT i.catid, c.name FROM items i 
  JOIN categories c ON i.catid=c.id 
  WHERE c.parent=1
  GROUP BY i.catid
  ORDER BY MAX(i.created) DESC;
```

Comment: I want the last updated categories. Categories which have latest items in them.